# "amp-app-banner" should not be hidden in Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: amp-html

I am currently using `amp-app-banner` (https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-app-banner/), but it seems like on Windows it only works in browsers other than Google Chrome and on iOS it only works in browsers other than Safari. The reason seems to be explained in the following line of their documentation:

> However, system-level app banners are shown when viewed with a browser on a compatible OS, such as Android and Chrome, or iOS and Safari. In those cases, the amp-app-banner is hidden to avoid redundancy.

To be honest, I don't really understand what that means / why it is set up to behave this way. Could someone please let me know if there is a way to get around this and always show `amp-app-banner` no matter the browser?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.